# Как называются глаголы, у которых нет определённых форм?

Tags: глаголы, словоизменение, времена

Например, у глагола *победить* нет будущего времени (в детстве постоянно хотелось сказать победжу с однозвучным -дж- ), а у глагола *гнести,* который, кстати, практически не употребляется в этой форме, нету прошедшего времени (но можно хотя бы заменить на *угнетал*).

*Почему так сложилось, что есть такие "неполноценные" слова и как они называются?* Буду рад ещё примерам подобных глаголов.

Comment: _Недостаточные» глаголы (глаголы с неполной личной парадигмой)._  === См. https://vuzlit.ru/843968/nedostatochnye_glagoly_glagoly_nepolnoy_lichnoy_paradigmoy_izobiluyuschie_glagoly_glagoly_dvumya_variantami

Comment: Спасибо, Слава!

Comment: @slava1947: неправильно там по ссылке написано про "кадить", "косить", "лихорадить". Пожалуйста: "кажу", "кошу", "лихоражу".